# Receive-side NIC teaming using LACP for use with NFS

Tags: linux, networking, bonding, lacp

I have a server with a 10G connection to a central switch. One NFS client has (2) gigabit NICS connected to the same switch. I'd like the NFS client to receive bandwidth of 2Gbps from the 10G server at any given time.

The main application that I use is NFS, and uses many threads. I know with LACP bonding I can enable mode 6 which round-robins based on source/destination IP and port. Since my client is running NFS, I'm wondering if I can get each NFS connection to use a variety of source ports so that each thread is load-balanced?

Answer (score 1):

The load balancing coming from the switch into a connected host (like the NFS client) is controlled by the switch.

That being said, an NFS mount is one single TCP/UDP connection, it cannot be load balanced across multiple NICs and still adhere to the 802.3ad LACP specification.

Your NFS client could have 2Gbps, comprising of 1Gbps to one NFS server and 1Gbps to another NFS server, but cannot have 2Gbps to a single NFS server.

If you need the client faster than 1Gbps, you need to buy a faster NIC.